# php date does not match database?

Tags: php

This is the coding and it is echoing with the right format but the fact that the date is wrong when it prints out.

> **Output:** 31 Dec 1969 19:33
>
> **Database Timestamp**  2016-05-20 21:53:17

```
<?php  
date_default_timezone_set('ECT');
$timestamp = 1456778973;
echo date('d M Y H:i',$row['timestamp']);
?>
```

and i have tried doing the date in different ways and still the same result

Comment: Database datetime fields should always be populated as UTC, then you add/subtract the timezone offset. using DateTime class.

Comment: Would you know what the offset would be? for mountain standard time?

Comment: Mountain Time   -> `America/Denver`  
Mountain Time (no DST) ->  `America/Phoenix`

Answer (score 2):

In the code sample you posted, `$row['timestamp']` has not been set, so the date is constructed with timestamp 0, also known as epoch, or the date that is being echoed.

If you change it as follows, it should work fine:

```
<?php  
date_default_timezone_set('ECT');
$timestamp = 1456778973;
echo date('d M Y H:i', $timestamp); ?>
```

**Side note:**
Time zone `ECT` is not a valid time zone code in PHP. If I assume correctly that you mean european central time, you would have to specify `CET` instead.

Comment: I want the timestamp to be provided from the database that is why i had the $row['timestamp'] and i was trying to set it to eastern central time for the east coast

Comment: @RKGaming Well, but in the script that you shared, `$row` was not set.

Comment: To refer to the US eastern time zone, you should use the time zone code `America/New_York`

Answer (score 1):

`ECT` doesn't exist as a valid `TimeZone`, did you mean `CET` perhaps?
The correct way to do this is using the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, i.e.:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(1456778973);
$tz = new DateTimeZone("America/Denver");
$date->setTimezone($tz);
echo $date->format('d M Y H:i');
```

---

[PHPFiddle Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/7q15-zdwy)

---

Note:

Dates should always be stored in DB as `UTC` (timestamp aka unix time), then you can add or subtract the timezone offset using the `DateTime` class.

---

> Would you know what the offset would be for mountain standard time?

Mountain Time: `America/Denver`
Mountain Time (no DST): `America/Phoenix`

[List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: I want the timestamp to be set to the database time stamp

Comment: There is no way to do that @RKGaming with an integer timestamp. It has no time zone associated with it. You can try timestamp / datetime fields

Comment: Past dates should be stored as UTC, but often future dates should be stored in their local timezone. Otherwise get unexpected behavior in case the timezone changes. If I want to meet you 2pm next wednesday but my government suddenly cancels DST this shouldn't affect our (local) meeting time.